# Grant select on tables with a specific naming pattern

Tags: sql-server, permissions

How to grant select on all tables starting with `VVC_`?

```
grant select on VVC_* to user1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming they're all in the `dbo` schema:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'GRANT SELECT ON dbo.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)
  + N' TO [User1];'
FROM sys.tables AS t
WHERE t.name LIKE N'VVC[_]%'
AND t.[schema_id] = 1;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

But Martin is right, it would be much better to use a schema than a string prefix.

Comment: I know it but can't do that. I can't modify schema. I will lose support.

Answer (score 7):

There is no inbuilt method for granting permissions on tables matching a pattern. You need to grant it to the individual tables.

It would be quite easy to generate the required script with a query against `sys.tables` for names `like 'VVC[_]%'` though.

Instead of using a VVC prefix you could create a VVC schema. Then you can grant select permissions on the schema. This would also cater for tables added in the future to the same schema.